# JavaScript regex symbol occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some problem with regex in JS. I wrote my regular expression:

```
/^([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s(\[.*\])\s+(.+)$/g
```

But it gives wrong result with one example:

```
WARN  2016-01-19 13:17:32,051 [localhost-startStop-1] Duplicate property values for key Data\ Df  : [ Date from] and [ Starting Day]
```

I want regex to divide the string in a such parts:

```
WARN
2016-01-19
13:17:32,051
[localhost-startStop-1]
Duplicate property values for key Data\ Df  : [ Date from] and [ Starting Day]
```

And everything OK, except last 2 parts. There I got:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] Duplicate property values for key Data\ Df  : [ Date from]
and [ Starting Day]
```

Why? I want to divide that part of string by first ] occurrence. Don't know why it takes the second.

PS: Here is the example: https://regex101.com/r/wG5xV6/2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the `.*` (that matches zero or more characters other than a newline, as many as possible) with a lazy dot matching `.*?` that matches zero or more characters other than a newline, as few as possible:

```
^([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s(\[.*?\])\s+(.+)$
                                    ^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI5gC0/1)

You can also shorten the pattern a bit by replacing `[^\s]` with `\S`:

```
^([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s(\[.*?\])\s+(.+)$
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI5gC0/2)

```js
var re = /^([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s(\[.*?\])\s+(.+)$/gm; 
var str = 'INFO 2016-01-20 08:03:21,113 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqu9pa9eq1cqr515yzwu7|6c240779]-HelperThread-#0] Connection to \'rander\' established. Notifying listeners...\nWARN  2016-01-19 13:17:32,051 [localhost-startStop-1] Duplicate property values for key Data\ Df  : [ Date from] and [ Starting Day]';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>"+ JSON.stringify([m[1],m[2],m[3],m[4], m[5]], 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: I would only use `/g` with `/m`. Without `/m`, `/g` makes no sense since the pattern is anchored at the start and end.

Comment: Then you need to rely on the lazy dot matching. I updated the answer. You can also use `\S+` there, BTW, since the string inside `[...]` does not contain a space.

Comment: There is a problem, because sometimes it may contains space symbol. For example: ERROR 2016-01-20 00:15:00,352 [GroovyScriptJob: eventGenerator-47] Exception during job execution

Comment: but at the first look now it works great. At the moment i don't see any mistakes

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/fT0jQ2/1) you can see an issue. Not sure how big the issue it is and whether you can have such entries with a space after `]` inside the outer `[...]`. The problem is that the `[...]` are balanced and nested, but JS does not support that.

Comment: it's OK. There won't be something like this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- `^(.*?)(\s*?)(\S*?)(\s*?)(\S*?)(\s*?)(\[.*?\])(\s*)(.*?)$`

Also change `\S` with `.`

- `\S` means not sapce.
- `?`means get less.
- The rules of this sentence can be expressed as follows

  `begin + word + space + word + space + word + space + word + space + word + end`
  It must find first `]`,so we use `?` to find it.
  if u want to change the format of this sentence,you can replace it use
  `($1)\r($3)\r($5)\r($7)\r($9)` or other.